# List length in scheme

Tags: scheme

Hi I am trying to write a program where given a list of lists check to see if they are equal in size and return #t if they are.

So for example if i were to write (list-counter? '((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9))) the program would return #t, and (list-counter? '((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8))) would return #f.

SO far this is what I have done:

```
 (define list-counter?
  (lambda (x)
    (if (list? x)
        (if (list?(car x))
      (let (l (length (car x))))
        (if (equal? l (length(car x))))
        (list-counter?(cdr x))
 ) ) ) ) )
```

I think where I am going wrong is after I set the length of l to the length of the first list. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this problem. For instance, by hand and going step-by-step:

```
(define (all-lengths lists)
  (if (null? lists)
      '()
      (cons (length (car lists))
            (all-lengths (cdr lists)))))

(define (all-equal? head lengths)
  (if (null? lengths)
      true
      (and (= head (car lengths))
           (all-equal? head (cdr lengths)))))

(define (list-counter? lists)
  (let ((lengths (all-lengths lists)))
    (all-equal? (car lengths) (cdr lengths))))
```

Let me explain the above procedures. I'm dividing the problem in two steps, first create a new list with the lengths of each sublist - that's what `all-lengths` does. Then, compare the first element in a list with the rest of the elements, and see if they're all equal - that's what `all-equal?` does. Finally, `list-counter?` wraps it all together, calling both of the previous procedures with the right parameters.

Or even simpler (and shorter), by using list procedures (higher-order procedures):

```
(define (list-counter? lists)
  (apply = (map length lists)))
```

For understanding the second solution, observe that `all-lengths` and `all-equal?` represent special cases of more general procedures. When we need to create a new list with the result of applying a procedure to each of the elements of another list, we use `map`. And when we need to apply a procedure (`=` in this case) to all of the elements of a list *at the same time*, we use `apply`. And that's exactly what the second version of `list-counter?` is doing.

Comment: Quick question, if I wanted the program to fail if I had an empty list like (list-counter? '( () )), or (list-counter? '( ( () ) ))  then would I just need another base case to check to make sure the list isn't null, like (if(not(null? lists)))?

Comment: Yes, you'd need an extra case - in fact, both solutions _assume_ that the list of lists has at least one element.

Comment: ... And the second solution expects at least two elements

Comment: Or at least, not consistently so across implementations.

Comment: @JasonFruit it seems that it's implementation-dependent

Comment: @Óscar López: exactly.  In mzscheme, (= 1) is an error, but in Guile and Ypsilon it returns #t.

Answer (score 1):

You could write an `all-equal?` function like so:

```
(define (all-equal? list)
  ;; (all-equal? '()) -> #t
  ;; (all-equal? '(35)) -> #t
  ;; (all-equal? '(2 3 2)) -> #f
  (if (or (null? list) (null? (cdr list)))
      #t
      (reduce equal? list)
  ))
```

then do:

```
(all-equal? (map length listOfLists))
```

---

Alternatively you can do:

```
(define (lists-same-size? list-of-lists)
    (if (== (length listOfLists) 0)
      #t
      (let*
        (( firstLength
             (length (car listOfLists)) )
         ( length-equal-to-first?
             (lambda (x) (== (length x) firstLength)) )
        )
        (reduce and #t (map length-equal-to-first? listOfLists))
      )
    )))
```

What this says is: if the list length is 0, our statement is vacuously true, otherwise we capture the first element of the list's length (in the 'else' part of the `if`-clause), put it in the closure defined by `let`'s syntactic sugar (actually a lambda), and use that to define an `length-equal-to-first?` function.

Unfortunately `reduce` is not lazy. What we'd really like is to avoid calculating lengths of lists if we find that just one is not equal. Thus to be more efficient we could do:

```
    ...
       (let*
         ...   
         ( all-match?               ;; lazy
             (lambda (pred list)
               (if (null? list) 
                   #t 
                   (and (pred (first list)) (all-match? (cdr list)))
                      ;;^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ stops recursion if this is false
             )) )
        )
        (all-match? length-equal-to-first? listOfLists)
      )
    )))
```

Note that `all-match?` is already effectively defined for you with MIT scheme's `(list-search-positive list pred)` or `(for-all? list pred)`, or in Racket as `andmap`.

---

*Why does it take so long to write?*

You are forced to write a base-case because your reduction has no canonical element since it relies on the first element, and list manipulation in most languages is not very powerful. You'd even have the same issue in other languages like Python. In case this helps:

second method:

```
if len(listOfLists)==0:
    return True
else:
    firstLength = len(listOfLists[0])
    return all(len(x)==firstLength for x in listOfLists)
```

However the first method is much simpler to write in any language, because it skirts this issue by ignoring the base-cases.

first method:

```
if len(listOfLists)<2:
    return True
else:
    return reduce(lambda a,b: a==b, listOfLists)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helped me understand what was going on. Was a bit confused by the pseudo for a bit but I get it now. :D

Comment: @gestalt: I rewrote it a lot and fixed a few mistakes, made it much cleaner.

Comment: @gestalt: Thanks for getting me to learn the difference between `fold` and `reduce` (the latter not forcing you to use an initial seed, generally a bad thing).

Answer (score 0):

This might sound a bit weird, but I think it is easy.

Run down the list, building a new list containing the length of each (contained) list, i.e. map length.

Run down the constructed list of lengths, comparing the head to the rest, return #t if they are all the same as the head. Return false as soon as it fails to match the head.